# Mapbox GL JS line animation

Tags: javascript, animation, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I am working with ~150,000 polylines that span North America. Across all the lines I'd like to draw/animate from the start to the end of each line. I started down the road of adding vertices to an array and updating a Mapbox source [like this example](http://%20https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-a-line/). This was not feasible given the size of the entire dataset. In geojson form it's about 800mb and manipulating this in the browser seemed unreasonable.

As an alternate approach, I've broken each polyline into equally sized segments of 10km in length. I added an attribute on each segment which represents its percent distance from the start. I created an interval below that triggers a setFilter event, filtering segments based in the percent from start.

```
currentLinPos=0;
lineInterval=setInterval(function(){
  currentLinPos+=.01;
  if(currentLinPos>0.9999){
    currentLinPos=0
  }
  map.setFilter('lines',['<','linePrc',currentLinPos])
}, 250);
```

Even when working with a small subset of the data, performance choppy and lags. I expected a better result from Mapbox GL but perhaps I need to rethink my data structure or approach entirely. Or would using something like [DECK.GL](https://deck.gl/#/) be far superior here?

Comment: [Use a texture to pattern the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341590/pure-webgl-dashed-line), add time to the texture lookup to [animate](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/Lbp1zav4/).